# Java Pattern matcher and RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I need RegEX help please... basically a pattern that matches the following strings

```
G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3]    
G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3]
G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3|R:2,3,4,5]
G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3|R:2,3,4,5]
```

"G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv" and "P:3" are the main thing to match

I've done the below to match the first string but got lost with the rest.

```
G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv(\[|\|)P:3(\||\])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the strings all begin with `G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv`.

After that, there is `[P:3]` by itself, or with either left `S:2,3,4|`, right `|R:2,3,4,5` or with both left and right. The values 2,3,4 and 2,3,4,5 could be repetitive digits divided by a comma.

To match the full pattern you could use:

[`(G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv)\[(?:S:(?:\d,)+\d\|)?(P:3)(?:\|R:(?:\d,)+\d)?\]`](https://regex101.com/r/xXxjQP/1)

**Explanation**

```
(G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv) # Match literally in group 1
\[                   # Match [
(?:                  # Non capturing group
  S:                 # Match literally
  (?:\d,)+\d\|       # Match repeatedly a digit and comma one or more times 
  \d\|               # Followed by a digit and |
)?                   # Close group and make it optional
(P:3)                # Capture P:3 in group 2
(?:                  # Non capturing group
  \|R:               # match |R:
  (?:\d,)+           # Match repeatedly a digit and comma one or more times
  \d                 # Followed by a digit
)?                   # Close group and make it optional
\]                   # Match ]
```

[Java Demo](http://rextester.com/TMT79411)

And for the `(?:\d,)+\d` you could also use `2,3,4` and `2,3,4,5` fi you want to match those literally.

To match the whole string with G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv at the start and should contain `P:3`, you could use a positive lookahead `(?=.*P:3)`:

[`\AG1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv(?=.*P:3).*\z`](http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyc5m16r)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

`"((G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv)\\[.*(?<=\\||\\[)P:3(?=\\]|\\,|\\|)[^\\]]*\\])"`

### Explanation:

`\\` - this is used in the regex to escape characters that have special meaning in regex

`G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv` these characters need to be matched literally (matching group #1 in parenthesis ("`()`")

`\\[.*` - `[` character and after it any character zero or more times

`(?<=\\||\\[)P:3` - positive lookbehind - here you say, you want `P:3` to be preceded by `|` OR `[`

AND

`P:3(?=\\]|\\,|\\|)` - positive lookahead - `P:3` to be followed only by `]` OR `,` OR `|` (if you don't want to match e.g.: `P:3,4`, simply delete the following part from the regex: `|\\,`

(`P:3`) - capturing group #2

`[^\\]]*` - there can appear zero or more characters other than `]`

`\\]` - `]` character at the end of match

### Code to check pattern:

```
String s1 = "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3]";
String s2 = "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3]";
String s3 = "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3|R:2,3,4,5]";
String s4 = "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3|R:2,3,4,5]";
String withCommaAfter = "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3,4]";
String notMatch1 ="G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:33]";
String notMatch2 = "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:33]";

String[] sampleStrings = new String[] {s1, s2, s3, s4, withCommaAfter, notMatch1, notMatch2}; // to store source strings and to print results in a loop
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv)\\[.*(?<=\\||\\[)(P:3)(?=\\]|\\,|\\|)[^\\]]*\\]");
for(String s : sampleStrings) {
    System.out.println("Checked String: \"" + s + "\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) { // if match is found print the following line to the console
        System.out.println("\t whole String  : " + m.group());
        System.out.println("\t G1...qRv part : " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("\t P:3      part : " + m.group(2) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Output that you get if you want String `withCommaAfter` to be matched too (if you don't want it to be matched, delete `|\\,` from the regex:

```
Checked String: "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3]"
     whole String  : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3]
     G1...qRv part : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv
     P:3      part : P:3

Checked String: "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3]"
     whole String  : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3]
     G1...qRv part : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv
     P:3      part : P:3

Checked String: "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3|R:2,3,4,5]"
     whole String  : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:3|R:2,3,4,5]
     G1...qRv part : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv
     P:3      part : P:3

Checked String: "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3|R:2,3,4,5]"
     whole String  : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3|R:2,3,4,5]
     G1...qRv part : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv
     P:3      part : P:3

Checked String: "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3,4]"
     whole String  : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:3,4]
     G1...qRv part : G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv
     P:3      part : P:3

Checked String: "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[P:33]"
Checked String: "G1:k6YxekrAP71LqRv[S:2,3,4|P:33]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution mate. Your expression didn't work check it out here https://regex101.com/r/7H9Y3Q/1

Comment: @zoro74 I updated my answer to cover the hole in my first attempt, hope it will be helpful some way :-)